# How to: embed @Ajax.ActionLink inside an HTMLselect list option?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to embed an `Ajax.ActionLink` inside an HTML select option as follows

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"</script>

<select>
    <option>@Ajax.ActionLink("Opiton 1", "MyAction", new { parameter = "parm1" }, 
        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,             
        LoadingElementId = "myDiv" })</option>
    <option>@Ajax.ActionLink("Opiton 2", "MyAction", new { parameter = "parm1" }, 
        new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,             
        LoadingElementId = "myDiv" })</option>
</select>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

The Action method

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string parameter)
{
    ViewModel myViewModel = new ViewModel();

    myViewModel.Parm = parameter;

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_MyPartial", myViewModel);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(myViewModel);
    }
}
```

When I place the `Ajax.ActionLink` outside of the select list, it works fine and goes straight to MyAction.  When I embed the link inside of an option in the select list, the onlclick event fails to fire.

How do I get the onclick event to fire inside of an `<option></option>`?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have 2 Action links inside the select element. I guess you want to call an action method and set the return value to a div. I would not use the Microsoft ajax libraries for this. I would do it by hand with **clean code** like this.( I need to refer only jQuery library in the page. Nothing else)

```
//include only jQuery library. Nothing else ! 

<select id="dropDown1">
   <option value="0"> Select</option>
   <option value="1"> Detroit</option>
   <option value="2"> Florida</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $("#dropDown1").change(function(){   
       $.get("@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")",
                                 { "parameter" : $(this).val()},function(data){
            $("#myDiv").html(data);
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but your code appears to have a syntax error in it.

Comment: @wayne.blackmon: I got it. It was a typo and a syntax issue. Fixed it now ( Tested. No errors now)

Comment: Again, thanks for the answer.   This technique almost works.  Unfortunately, the view is not changing.  The view code is <div id="myDiv">@Html.Parial("_MyParial")</div>. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @wayne.blackmon: I encourage you to write another question with **ONLY relevant details**.